# Angular 2 webpack + typescript can not find root component

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Angular 2 with webpack + typescript can not find root component unless the script tag for the application entry file is located after the custom element.

Could anyone tell me is this happening?

Am I missing a set in the bootstrapping process?

Is there a way to wait for the page to load before angular 2 starts looking for the route component element?

**Not working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Express</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost:8080/dist/main_style.css' />
      <script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
      <script src="dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Is Working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Express</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost:8080/dist/main_style.css' />
      <script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
      <!--<script src="dist/main.bundle.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**'boot.ts' file**

```
// Angular 2
import 'angular2/platform/browser';
import 'angular2/platform/common_dom';
import 'angular2/core';
import 'angular2/router';
import 'angular2/http';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';

import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it is because when you have the webpack bundle at the top, all of the Angular 2 scripts are being run before the DOM has been fully fluffed out.  Meaning that Angular 2 is trying to boot, but the `<my-app></my-app>` tag has not been rendered yet.